# How to make the new captured image to instantly get the watermark by clicking of a button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, watermark

so I have a small project about a camera app when I click on the *Floating Action Button*, not only it can save the image, but I cannot add the watermark directly after the new image is taken. I ran out of ideas on how to make this is what I want to know is how to make the watermarks from the *Textviews*, to apply on to the new photo that I made and automatically saves it. I used *Canvas*, *Paint* and *Bitmap* for this and none of them seems to try and make it work. It saves only the raw image that is been captured within the device.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

**Gradle implements**

```
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha21'
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.022"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test_view"
            android:textColor="#E91E63" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:backgroundTint="#B8AEAE"
        app:borderWidth="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.bitmapwatermark

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Color.RED
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    /**watermark private variables**/
    private var paint = Paint()
    private val config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    private val width = 1
    private val height = 1
    private var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)

    /**Camera variables**/
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /**Checking for all permissions to be granted through method,
         * if so it will start the camera, if not checks for a request with permissions and request code**/
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Making a variable, connecting to the button and setting up a listener to initiate taking a photo through a method
        val imageCaptureBtn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.camera_button)
        imageCaptureBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto().apply {
                drawBitmap(bitmap, left = 5f, top = 5f, paint)
            }
        }

        // Connecting the late init variable with a new method to get output directory
        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull().let {
            File(it, "BitmapWatermark").apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        val photoFile = File(outputDirectory, SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        imageCapture?.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object  : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val saveUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile).apply { drawBitmap(bitmap, left = 5f, top = 5f, paint) }
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $saveUri"

                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, msg)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Photo capture failed: ${exception.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    photoFile.delete()
                }

            }
        )
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val viewFinder = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.previewView)
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun drawBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, left: Float, top: Float, paint: Paint?) {
        val textText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testText)
        val paintText = Paint()

        paintText.textAlign
        paintText.textSize = 14F
        paintText.color = RED

        paintText.getTextPath(textText.toString(), 1, 10, 12f, 12f, path)

    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CadIS for Android"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        private var path: Path = Path() // this gets us the new image
    }
}
```

If anyone knows the problem why it doesn't put the watermark from the *TextView* as the same position as the main xml file, please show me where to put and what to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://medium.com/@guygriv/adding-a-text-watermark-to-a-bitmap-f3af0974c430 check this post it might help you

Comment: @KrishnaSony I tried it, but then when I placed the method and added all the details I need as a test, taking the picture, still doesn't show the watermark after I take a photo.